# How to use the new NavigationStack for navigation in SwiftUI 4+ (iOS 16+)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I've read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack) on the topic and I believe I have a basic understanding of it.
In theory, it sound pretty good, and not too complex. If i have a model class `ModelClass` and a view to display the details of the model, `ModelDetailsView`, I can just append the model instance to the `NavigationPath` and have a `.navigationDestination(for: ModelClass.self)` modifier ready to receive the data and display the details view.

So the project setup in simplified terms would be like this:

The `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var navigator = Navigator()

    var body: some View {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $navigator.path) {
                MainMenu()
                    .navigationDestination(for: ModelClass.self) { model in
                        ModelDetailsView(model: model)
                    }
            }
            .environmentObject(navigator)
        }
    }
}
```

The `Navigator` class:

```swift
class Navigator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()

    func navigate(with model: any Hashable) {
        path.append(model)
    }
}
```

And we have the navigation in the `MainMenu`:

```swift
struct MainMenu: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigator: Navigator
    let model = ModelClass()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Go to details") {
            navigator.navigate(with: model)
        }
    }
}
```

I have multiple problems with the above mentioned method.

First, at the navigation part (`navigator.navigate(with: model)`), I'm not really specifying my intentions in the code. From that single line, it's not clear if I'm trying to navigate to a details view, or to any other view that uses this class instance as a property. And adding comments kind of ruin the cleanliness of the swift code (for me at least).

But whatever, if I had to, I would write comments to clarify that this is supposed to take me to a details view. But this next problem is far worse...

So what if I have multiple views that take this exact class as property? Let's say I have this `ModelDetailsView`, but I also have a `SecondaryDetailsView`. These two views take only one argument, and it's a `ModelClass` for both. Now, how should I write the `.navigationDestination` modifier, to distinguish between these two? I could do

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: ModelClass.self) { model in
    if someCondition {
        ModelDetailsView(model: model)
    } else {
        SecondaryDetailsView(model: model)
    }
}
```

but than, this `someCondition` has to be in the `ContentView`, which is neither practical nor a good practice.

Some place (I couldn't find the source) suggested to use `String`s as identifiers when navigating. So the Navigator would have a function

```swift
func show<V>(_ viewType: V.Type) where V: View {
    path.append(String(describing: viewType.self))
}
```

And that could be used like

```swift
navigator.show(ModelDetailsView.self)
// or
navigator.show(SecondaryDetailsView.self)
```

The problem with this one is that you can't pass arguments to the views.

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { id in
    if id == String(describing: ModelDetailsView.self) {
        ModelDetailsView(model: ) // how do I get the model for the view?
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering if anyone has a good solution to this, that could be used in even larger projects without getting too ugly.

Comment: Instead of adding the same model to the stack and then deciding somewhere else where this should take you, just use different identifers for different destinations. You could use strings (as you suggested), but an enum is probably cleaner. You could use an enum with associated values if you want to pass data at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Benzy Neez suggested in the comments, it would be suitable to use an enum with associated values as the type of the navigation path. The names of each case can represent the type of view (whether it be `details`, or `secondaryDetails`), and the associated value can store the models you want to pass to the view.

```
enum Destination: Hashable {
    case details(of: ModelClass) // assuming ModelClass is Hashable
    case secondaryDetails(of: ModelClass)
}
```

The `navigate` method can then take a `Destination`:

```
func navigate(to destination: Destination) {
    path.append(destination)
}
```

A usage like `navigate(to: .details(of: someModel))` would be very readable.

The `navigationDestination(for:destination:)` modifier can check which case of the enum it is:

```
.navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { dest in
    switch dest {
    case let .details(of: model):
        ModelDetailsView(model: model)
    case let .secondaryDetails(of: model):
        SecondaryDetailsView(model: model)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the best solution to me. Very clean and elegant. Also thanks to @BenzyNeez for the suggestion!