# NavigationStack wrong data details

Tags: swiftui

I have an issue with passing the News structure deep into the navigation stack. Each displayed detail has the label 'First' even though we have three different sets of data. Do you know where is the issue or there is better way to add navigation.

Scenario:

1. User tap on first cell
2. User receives details with correct data

[image]

This is my code

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            TabView {
                ListView(navPath: $navPath)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("First", systemImage: "newspaper")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath
    let news: [News] = [.init(name: "First"), .init(name: "Second"), .init(name: "Third")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            List(news) { new in
                CellView(news: new, navPath: $navPath)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum CellRouter: Hashable {
    case details
}

struct CellView: View {
    let news: News
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            HStack {
                Button(news.name) {
                    navPath.append(CellRouter.details)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: CellRouter.self) { router in
                switch router {
                case .details:
                    CellViewDetails(news: news, navPath: $navPath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct News: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}

struct CellViewDetails: View {
    let news: News
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            Text(news.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need so many `NavigationStack`s. Just put one in each tab. `TabView` should be the root.

Comment: But how to display navigationTitle then or give ability to further navigation e.g from details to another screen?

Comment: Just do `.navigationTitle("Foo")` as you normally do. And you have the navigation path, append to it to go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need that many `NavigationStack`s. `NavigationStack`s are not designed to be nested, and nesting them will get SwiftUI very confused. Just put one in each tab and that's enough. You can pass the navigation paths down the hierarchy with `@Binding`/`@EnvironmetObject` or otherwise, and other views can append to it to navigate to somewhere else.

Second, value-based navigation works by storing *everything* needed to create each navigation destination in the navigation path, so an enum with only one possible value won't work if you want to show different `News`s. With only one possible value, all you can show is the same view.

Third, you should not put multiple `.navigationDestination(for:)` in the same navigation stack, unless they are for different types. You are putting `navigationDestination(for: CellRouter.self)` in each `CellView` right now, and this is not correct. The destinations for one type should be decided in a single `navigationDestination(for:)` modifier.

To do this correctly, let's fix `CellRouter` first. Add an associated `News` value to the `details` case. Now `CellRouter` has all the information we need to create the destinations.

```
enum CellRouter: Hashable {
    case details(news: News)

    // presumably you have other cases here...
}

struct News: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}
```

Then, let's move the `navigationDestination` to the `List`:

```
List(news) { new in
    CellView(news: new, navPath: $navPath)
}
.navigationDestination(for: CellRouter.self) { router in
    switch router {
    case .details(let news):
        CellViewDetails(news: news, navPath: $navPath)
    }
}
```

Here is the full code with the extra `NavigationStack`s removed:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("First", systemImage: "newspaper")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @State var navPath: NavigationPath = .init()
    let news: [News] = [.init(name: "First"), .init(name: "Second"), .init(name: "Third")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            List(news) { new in
                CellView(news: new, navPath: $navPath)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: CellRouter.self) { router in
                switch router {
                case .details(let news):
                    CellViewDetails(news: news, navPath: $navPath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum CellRouter: Hashable {
    case details(news: News)
    // presumably you have other cases here
}

struct CellView: View {
    let news: News
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(news.name) {
            navPath.append(CellRouter.details(news: news))
        }
    }
}

struct News: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}

struct CellViewDetails: View {
    let news: News
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(news.name)
    }
}
```

Recommended reading: some of my answers about value-based navigation:

- [SwiftUI how to navigate to nested navigation link pages in NavigationStack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77491311/5133585)
- [How to use the new NavigationStack for navigation in SwiftUI 4+ (iOS 16+)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77337569/5133585)

Comment: Thanks for great solution and your time :)